# In C# running the PowerShell script first and then invoke() error

Tags: c#, powershell

I would like to make printer-installer gui with c#, but I given error.
my error is as below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ENIu.png)

> System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: 'The term 'Add'
> is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
> operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
> included, verify that the path is correct and try again.'

my codes are below, where could i be doing wrong? I'm waiting for your help please. I've been struggling for 3 days, I looked at all the resources but I couldn't find a solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace son1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ekle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

using (System.Management.Automation.PowerShell powershell = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create())
{
    powershell.AddCommand("Add");
    powershell.AddArgument("-");
    powershell.AddArgument("PrinterPort");
    powershell.AddArgument("-");
    powershell.AddArgument("name");
    powershell.AddArgument(printer_ip);
    powershell.AddArgument("-");
    powershell.AddArgument("PrinterHostAddress");
    powershell.AddArgument(printer_ip);
    powershell.Invoke();
}
using (System.Management.Automation.PowerShell powershell = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create())
{
    powershell.AddCommand("Add");
    powershell.AddArgument("-");
    powershell.AddArgument("Printer");
    powershell.AddArgument("-");
    powershell.AddArgument("Name");
    powershell.AddArgument(printer_name);
    powershell.AddArgument("-");
    powershell.AddArgument("PortName");
    powershell.AddArgument(printer_ip);
    powershell.AddArgument("-");
    powershell.AddArgument("DriverName");
    powershell.AddArgument("Canon Generic Plus PCL6");
    powershell.Invoke();
}
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Success!");

            

}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is a little more sophisticated than requiring you to input every single string token manually.

`AddCommand()` takes the whole command name at once:

```
powershell.AddCommand('Add-Printer');
```

For named parameter arguments, use `AddParameter()` instead of `AddArgument()`:

```
powershell.AddParameter("Name", ad);
powershell.AddParameter("PortName", ip)
// etc...
```

Note that the `-` that we usually use in front of parameter names in PowerShell scripts is not actually *part of the name itself*, so don't include that.

---

If you want to execute multiple pipelines as separate statements, call `AddStatement()` in between the call to `AddCommand()` for the first command in the next pipeline:

```
using (System.Management.Automation.PowerShell powershell = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create())
{
    // call `Add-PrinterPort ...`
    powershell.AddCommand("Add-PrinterPort");
    powershell.AddParameter("Name", printer_ip);
    powershell.AddParameter("PrinterHostAddress", printer_ip);

    // terminate previous statement (equivalent to a newline or `;` in powershell)
    powershell.AddStatement();

    // then call `Add-Printer ...`
    powershell.AddCommand("Add-Printer");
    powershell.AddParameter("Name", printer_name);
    powershell.AddParameter("PortName", printer_ip);
    powershell.AddParameter("DriverName", "Canon Generic Plus PCL6");

    // Invoke the whole thing at once
    powershell.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. its running